# Does Stokes' Theorem hold on spaces with singular points?

Tags: differential-geometry, orbifolds

I have come across the question whether Stokes' theorem holds also on orbifolds.

Let us take the simple case of $T^2/Z_2$ with a one-form $A$, then the question becomes:

- For a region $\Gamma$ with boundary $\partial\Gamma$ is $\int_\Gamma \mathrm dA = \int_{\partial \Gamma} A$, even if some of the fix poitns of the orbifold lie within $\Gamma$?
- As a special case: Is $\int_\mathcal M \mathrm dA = 0$ if $\mathcal M$ is the entire orbifold?
- What changes if $A$ is a non-trivial $U(1)$ bundle? How do I properly incorporate this?

As you might guess, I'm a physicists and the application I am interested in is a $U(1)$ gauge theory on the $T^2/Z_2$ orbifold.

Comment: Your question needs a lot of improvement, there are several things about it that do not make sense. To start with, in your first bullet point, where would a fix point of an orbifold $\Gamma$ lie if it did not lie within $\Gamma$? Also in your first bullet point, what does $A$ represent?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for pointing out the inaccuracies. I edited my question and hope that now it is clear enough. $\Gamma$ was not supposed to be the entire orbifold, but just a region on it. Rather obviousely I can apply Stokes' theorem if $\Gamma$ does not contain any singular points, but if singular points lie within $\Gamma$ I am unsure.

Comment: Stokes' theorem is one that likes to be true in almost any context you can imagine.  Manifolds are the "deluxe" place where the proofs are particularly easy.  But there are versions of Stokes' theorem on all kinds of relatively degenerate spaces.  Stratified spaces, orbifolds and such.  I suspect the only reason why there's no proof in "full generality" is it's not clear how general a theorem people would like.  So people just prove versions of it as they need it.  Off the top of my head I don't see any problems proving it for orbifolds, but I have to run off to teach now...

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you for your comment. Would I pick up kind of "residues" at the fixed points of an orbifold?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you would like to state it, but I suspect it would naturally be stateable pretty much exactly like the normal Stokes theorem.  One would only have to worry about special properties of residues when integrating singular objects, distributions and such.